# Apache Rewrite Rule on Dispatcher

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect, apache2

How can I do a rewrite rule for both `http://example.com/abc` to rewrite/redirect to `http://example.com/abc.html` but it should work when I have the URL as `http://example.com/abc/def.html`. Currently when I do `redirect 301 "abc" "abc.hml"`, the second URL is also redirecting to `http://example.com/abc.html/def.html`.

My current rules.

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/index.html$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L]
RedirectMatch ^/abc$ /abc.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(.*)$

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/$1/ [L]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html    
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on  
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently when I do `redirect 301 "abc" "abc.hml"`, the second URL is also redirecting to `http://example.com/abc.html/def.html`.

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix matching*, which explains your undesirable redirect.

But also, don't mix redirects from both mod_alias (ie. `RedirectMatch` and `Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`). Since they are different modules, they execute at different times (usually mod_rewrite first) regardless of the apparent order, so you can end up with confusing conflicts.

Try the following in your server config, to internally *rewrite* `/abc` to `/abc.html`

```
RewriteRule ^/abc$ /abc.html [L]
```

However, you will have problems if `/abc` is a physical directory on the file system since mod_dir will normally try to "fix" the URL by appending a slash. So, you would need to make the trailing slash optional:

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/?$ /abc.html [L]
```

Also, disable `MultiViews` if it is enabled already:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

`MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) does the same sort of thing (internally rewrite `/abc` to `/abc.html` or `/abc.php` or whatever it finds) but will execute *before* mod_rewrite gets a chance.

Comment: Since your question was tagged `.htaccess`, I initially answered with respect to per-directory rewrites in .htaccess. It seems these directives are directly in the server config - I've updated my answer. The `RewriteRule` _patterns_ will need a slash prefix when used in the server config. In .htaccess, the directory-prefix is first removed from the URL-path that is matched, so the pattern does not start with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  Some one helped me in the site with this.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/abc/?$ /abc.html [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/(index\.html)?$ /content/aaa-123/abc.html [PT,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an _external redirect_, not an _internal rewrite_ (as in your other directives and in my answer)? The `NC` flag is also unnecessary here - in fact, this could result in duplicate content issues.

Comment: It to work apache with AEM dispatcher.